# FallbackResource doesn't rewrite php files

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mod-dir

I'm just using the following `.htaccess` config. But when I try to access a non-existent `.php` file, eg. `xyz.php`, the server returns a 404 instead of rewriting to `index.php`. What am I missing?

```
RewriteEngine on
FallbackResource /index.php
```

Comment: Are there  any other directives in your htaccess?

Comment: nope,i think its a bug https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52403

Comment: This isn't necessarily a bug (although it certainly feels like it is), it would seem to depend on how PHP is configured - as an Apache handler (`SetHandler` / `AddHandler`) or as FastCGI? In this case, the PHP handler would seem to take priority as `FallbackResource` only applies to the _default_ handler. (?)

Comment: Btw, `RewriteEngine` has nothing to do with `FallbackResource`, which is part of mod_dir.